# INCONSISTENCY UPDATING all salaries of a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to increase all salaries of the employee table with the following procedure.
The problem is that the salary column is doing something weird, is working like a variable, because is saving the salary of the last employee in the cursor and adding up to the next employee, so, at the end I got an error
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

```
    PROCEDURE increase_salaries AS
    v_emp NUMBER;
    v_sal NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        FOR r1 IN cur_emps LOOP
        v_emp := r1.employee_id;
        v_sal := r1.salary;
            UPDATE employees_copy
            SET
            salary = salary + salary;
            COMMIT;
               -- salary = salary + salary * v_salary_increase_rate;

        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS  THEN
            print('Error in employee '||v_emp);
    END increase_salaries;
```

Thanks

I knwo that I can use first a SELECT INTO for the actual salary and re-initialized it to 0, but I saw many examples on internet using UPDATE salary = salary + ... and it works but with my code does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table with:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees_copy (
  salary NUMBER(6,2)
);
```

Then you can put values from `-9999.99` to `9999.99` into the column. If you try to set a value that is outside those bounds then you will get the error:

> ```
> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
> ```

You can either:

1. Use a smaller value; or
2. Increase the precision of the column using:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE employees_copy MODIFY (salary NUMBER(7,2));
   ```

   and then you can put values from `-99999.99` to `99999.99` into the column.

---

However, you probably also need to fix your procedure to only update a single employee at each loop iteration (rather than updating all employees every loop iteration):

```sql
PROCEDURE increase_salaries AS
BEGIN
  FOR r1 IN cur_emps LOOP
    UPDATE employees_copy
    SET   salary = 2 * salary;
    WHERE employee_id = r1.employee_id;
  END LOOP;
END increase_salaries;
/
```

*Note 1: Don't catch the `OTHERS` exception. Let the exception happen and then you can debug it.*

*Note 2: Don't `COMMIT` in the procedure; if you do then you cannot chain together multiple procedures and `ROLLBACK` them all if one fails. Instead, `COMMIT` from wherever you are calling the procedure.*

Comment: Thaks for answering, you are right, I just do some testing and if want to increase all employees, I have two options. I can use  
UPDATE employees_copy
            SET
            salary = salary + salary *   v_salary_increase_rate

Comment: without a LOOP and the way you wrote using the employee_id LOOPING the cursor.
The way I did it was because I saw a tutorial and the code was just like that, I think they wanted to do it just like you did it,
but they forgot to use WHERE employee_id = r1.employee_id;, so that's why inconsistency happens in my code, cause Oracle uses salary
as variable and start saving the value of the last employee and suming up the same value.
Thank you